# Marshaling native method that return struct

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm trying to marshal a struct that is returned by my native code but I get `System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException`
It is not a output argument that already answered in other posts, it is return type.

C++ code:

```cpp
typedef struct
{
    bool success;
    ErrorCode error_code;
    char error_path[1025];
} Result;

DLLEXPORT Result GetResult();
```

`ErrorCode` is an enum,
C# equivalent:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Result
{
    public byte success;
    public ErrorCode error_code;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I1, SizeConst = 1025)]
    public char[] error_path;
}

[DllImport("shared", EntryPoint = "GetReult", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static Result GetResult();
```

I know the return stucts in [C# p/invoke should be blitable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/blittable-and-non-blittable-types) type but I don't know if I can make my struct blittable using the Marshaling directives or not.
Is there any way do do that or is something other is wrong with my code?
If there is no way I need to change my API and make the return type as output argument.

Thanks.

Comment: Do not use char.  A char in c++ is one byte while in c# it is a class object.  Instead of char use byte.

Comment: @jdweng a char in .net is a unicode char

Comment: @jdweng `char` in C# is a two byte UTF16 value type, not a class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: It is not UTF16 because there is a property that indicates if it is one or two  bytes.

Comment: @jdweng Had you followed the link in my previous comment you would have read this: _Represents a character as a UTF-16 code unit._ Are you just making stuff up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it blittable by using a fixed size buffer:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct Result
{
    public byte success;
    public ErrorCode error_code;
    public fixed sbyte error_path[1025];
}
```

Note that I have used `sbyte` for the array element type. That's an 8 bit type that matches the unamanged `char` type which is also an 8 bit type. You used `char` in your C# which is a 16 bit type.

You may need to convert the fixed size buffer to a string, but exactly how to do that depends upon the encoding that you used. However, there are plenty of articles on that topic (converting fixed size buffer to string) that you can find by web search.

Comment: @SimonMourier Regarding your now deleted answer, the blittable type tester from https://aakinshin.net/posts/blittable/ says that your type is not blittable. I think that the key phrase from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/blittable-and-non-blittable-types) is: _However, a type that contains a variable array of blittable types is not itself blittable._